LiFePO4 charge with Perfectpower DDC DC-DC converter
I have an electrical installation in my van to charge a gel battery from the alternator, using a domestic Perfectpower DDC DC-DC converter.
I want to change the gel battery to a LiFePO4 battery.
In the specifications of the Perfectpower it does not say that it is prepared to charge lithium-ion batteries. I can configure the Switchover voltage/constant voltage and the float voltage with pins.
Is this enough to make it work? Which values should be configured to charge a 12 V battery?

We can't speak for the manufacturer but they can.

The problem may be that, according to the specs, the Perfectpower DCC doesn't appear to have a constant current stage. That's fine for a lead acid battery (because it limits the charging current). But it's bad for a Li-ion battery (which doesn't limit the current). The likely result is a damaged DDC and a degraded LFP Li-ion battery. You need a device that is current limited as well as voltage regulated.
